# how to make my app running in iPhone 5 with just letterbox (landscape) mode??

Tags: ios, screen

I have an `app(landscape mode only app)` programmed for `iphone 3GS to 4S`, however when i try to run it in my `iPhone5` , the app just shift to left. i cannot see the `letterbox mode`.

In my program , i have a lot of customize `UIView` components that are added to my `UIViewController` view programmatically, as follows:

```
MyView *myview = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 180, 300) ];
[self addSubView:myview]
```

how can I make my run in iPhone5 in just letterbox mode, without a lot code change?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your project includes the 4-inch launch image (`Default-568h@2x.png`). Just remove it, it should do the trick. When running on iPhone 5, any app that doesn't include this launch image is run in letterbox mode.

Comment: but i have only black screen there , nothing i have there

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's black or what's in the image, just its presence lets iOS decide how to run it. If the file is present, you won't get letterbox.

Comment: i delete that default black idiot default picture, then it works! you are my hero !! bravo!!

Comment: sorry, i got the problem again in ios 5 with 4 -inch simulator. do you know how to fix it in this case?

Comment: One thing that often happens in the simulator is that old files are kept hanging around in the app bundle files. I bet that's the explanation, that launch image is still actually there. Try quitting your app then deleting it from the simulator (or delete the files yourself from the simulator's files on your Mac).